# Combining Web Component Script References Within a Single File

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I have successfully implemented web components into my application, which has cut down on the length of the index.html file considerable. The only part that bugs me at this point is the lengthy list of web component script references, like so:

```
  <script src="web-components/ScheduleManager.js"></script>
  <script src="web-components/ActionButtons.js"></script>
  <script src="web-components/DetailsPane.js"></script>
  <script src="web-components/PageHeaderLinks.js"></script>
  <script src="web-components/SideBarHeader.js"></script>
  <script src="web-components/JobsTableHeader.js"></script>
  <script src="web-components/ModuleMenus.js"></script>
  <script src="web-components/SelectDetailsPane.js"></script>
  //... more web components
```

What I'm looking for is a simple way to group these web components in a separate file, and then import that one file into my index.html file, just so I don't have so many of these `<script>` references on the index.html page itself, which I'm trying to keep terse.

What is the simplest way to accomplish this? I don't need additional pre-processing. Just a simple way to group these web components into a single `<script>` reference, or something similar.

Comment: Why not make a web component that has the innerHTML of all these script files? Might be overkill, but it is a pretty easy solution.

Comment: Well, because modularity is one of the huge wins with web components. So storing them as one file kind of puts as back where we were before we had them. I just want to cut down on the number of script references on my index.html page. And I was hoping to do that by handling that elsewhere in a singular way, and then pulling in that one singular file that handles it.

Comment: So is what you want to add the script only if you use it? Or to add them all in just one script?

Comment: The latter: just to add them all in one script.

Comment: If your ``index.html`` relies on all these components (in other words, they all need to be defined before your page actually does something meaningful) Then it might be better to include (all required) components with <SCRIPT> tags in the <HEAD> of your ``index.html`` That way all components are defined before use, AND you get the added benefit that GZIP has optimized your (now bigger) HTML file. Will take some more CI/CD work to go from seperate source code files to one delivered HTML file (because all bundlers still focus on JS code). Only include Components for the LCP https://web.dev/lcp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply import them as ES Modules. Create a file `components.js` right next to your `index.html`:

```js
import { ScheduleManager } from 'web-components/ScheduleManager.js';
import { ActionButtons } from 'web-components/ActionButtons.js';
import { DetailsPane } from 'web-components/DetailsPane.js';
import { PageHeaderLinks } from 'web-components/PageHeaderLinks.js';
import { SideBarHeader } from 'web-components/SideBarHeader.js';
import { JobsTableHeader } from 'web-components/JobsTableHeader.js';
import { ModuleMenus } from 'web-components/ModuleMenus.js';
import { SelectDetailsPane } from 'web-components/SelectDetailsPane.js';
```

In your webcomponents files, `export` the classes, example:

```js
export class ScheduleManager extends HTMLElement {
```

Last step: Link the components.js in your HTML with `type="module"` in the `<head>`:

```html
<script src="./components.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: This worked with one tweak - making sure to also export the files from the `components.js` file. Thanks!

Comment: If you get a CORS error for your js script using this method, it's because ES6 Modules don't work when loading from the `file:///` protocol. You need to install `live-server` using npm, and then execute the command in the same folder as your index.html

Answer (score 0):

If your scripts are activated only if they meet certain elements in the html (i.e. SelectDetailsPane.js only works if there really is a details pane in this page, otherwise it does nothing) you can create a single big script, maybe minify it, and then include it in every page. Every component in the big file must check if the actual page needs it.
This will shorten your html document and enhance the speed of your website becuse the browser only needs one request to get all the component's js (it's faster to download one big file than many little ones)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice solution that is super easy to use.

In your index.html:

```
<script src="loader.js"></script>
```

In loader.js:

```
const scriptSources = ["web-components/ScheduleManager.js", "web-components/ActionButtons.js", "web-components/DetailsPane.js", "web-components/PageHeaderLinks.js", "web-components/SideBarHeader.js", "web-components/JobsTableHeader.js", "web-components/ModuleMenus.js", "web-components/SelectDetailsPane.js"];

for(var i = 0; i < scriptSources.length; i++) {
  let newNode = document.createElement("script");
  newNode.src = scriptSources[i];
  document.head.appendChild(newNode);
}
// although it may seem like we can just use += on innerHTML, that is actually disallowed in html5.
```

Here is an example:

```js
const scriptSources = new Array(3).fill("data:text/plain;charset=utf-8;base64,Y29uc29sZS5sb2coImV4ZWN1dGVkIik=");
// The data URI above encode 'console.log("executed")'. It is just filling an array so it executes three times. You could just use a normal array of srces like shown above.

for(var i = 0; i < scriptSources.length; i++) {
  let newNode = document.createElement("script");
  newNode.src = scriptSources[i];
  document.head.appendChild(newNode);
}
```

Note that using the above means **all of these scripts will execute after anything else in the head has** executed. If you have something that depends on previous scripts in your `head`:

```html
<head>
    <script src="loader.js"></script>
    <Component>Component Here</Component>
</head>
```

`Component` might have issues. To solve this, you can change `loader.js` to the following:

```
const script = document.currentScript;
const scriptSources = ["web-components/ScheduleManager.js", "web-components/ActionButtons.js", "web-components/DetailsPane.js", "web-components/PageHeaderLinks.js", "web-components/SideBarHeader.js", "web-components/JobsTableHeader.js", "web-components/ModuleMenus.js", "web-components/SelectDetailsPane.js"];

for(var i = 0; i < scriptSources.length; i++) {
  let newNode = document.createElement("script");
  newNode.src = scriptSources[i];
  script.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, script.nextSibling);
}
```

Here is an example of the above:

```html
<script>
const script = document.currentScript;
const scriptSources = ["data:text/plain;charset=utf-8;base64,Y2xhc3MgQ29tcG9uZW50IGV4dGVuZHMgSFRNTEVsZW1lbnQgew0KY29uc3RydWN0b3IoKSB7DQogICBzdXBlcigpOw0KdGhpcy5pbm5lckhUTUwgPSAiSXQgV29ya2VkISI7DQogIH0NCn0NCmN1c3RvbUVsZW1lbnRzLmRlZmluZSgnY29tcC1vbmVudCcsIENvbXBvbmVudCk7"];
// the above makes a web component that sets the innerHTML to "It Worked!"
for(var i = 0; i < scriptSources.length; i++) {
  let newNode = document.createElement("script");
  newNode.src = scriptSources[i];
  script.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, script.nextSibling);
}
</script>
<comp-onent>It didn't work.</comp-onent>
```